# Java ResultSet next() and previous() buttons are not working

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm trying to scroll through the rows in my database. For some reason my previous and next buttons are not working. Next button displays just first row and previous button doesn't display anything. My first and last buttons are working.

```
private void previousbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   try
    {            
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);            
       Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE");
                if (rs.previous())
                {
                    str1 = rs.getString("emp_id");
                    emp_id.setText(str1);
                    str2 = rs.getString("emp_fname");
                    first_name.setText(str2);
                    str3 = rs.getString("emp_lname");
                    last_name.setText(str3);
                }
                else
                {
                    rs.next();
                }

        con.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeGUI.this, err.getMessage());
    }     
}                                           

private void nextbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try
    {            
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);            
        Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee");

        if (rs.next())
        {  
            str1 = rs.getString("emp_id");
            emp_id.setText(str1);
            str2 = rs.getString("emp_fname");
            first_name.setText(str2);
            str3 = rs.getString("emp_lname");
            last_name.setText(str3); 
        }
        else
        {
            rs.previous();
        }            
    }        
    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeGUI.this, err.getMessage());
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) the javadoc for `ResultSet` and this is what it says:

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of
>   data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The
>   next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns
>   false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be
>   used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

So, when you get the `ResultSet` object, it will always be placed before the previous row and hence, `previous()` will always return `false`.

Assuming you are trying to implement Pagination with these buttons, I would recommend having a look at MySQL SELECT [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) and use `limit` to get the rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

You can use it with `LIMIT i, 1` where `i` will increment with each click of `next` and decrement with each click of `previous`.

Comment: No I'm not trying to implement Pagination. It's just a database table with a bunch of rows. First button will display first row of the table, last button will display last row. Next and previous buttons will jump back and forward between the rows.

Comment: That's exactly what the pagination is :)

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're talking about. Basically what you're saying the only thing that needs to be changed is sql code, and not the actual program?